# Visual Recognition Software for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, camera

Is there an object recognition software for the Raspberry Pi that is available for everybody to use, and that ends up being free? Whenever I search online, I always find OpenCV and facial recognition software instead of feature or object recognition. Any insights, thoughts, or ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV can do object detection.

There are several tutorials online including:

[Image Recognition and Object Detection](http://www.learnopencv.com/image-recognition-and-object-detection-part1/) 
[How to Detect and Track Object With OpenCV](https://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-detect-and-track-object-with-opencv/)

I also found this book very helpful:

[Raspberry Pi Computer Vision Programming](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/raspberry-pi-computer-vision-programming)